# Compare the values of UILables in two custom cells

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel, hidden

I have a tableview using a custom cell per row. Per cell/row I have 3 Labels. The first label of the 3 contains a number(day). This is the same on each row. The problem is some Labels contain the same value on the next row and what I would like to achieve is that if the value on the next row is the same as the value on the current row. The Label on the next row becomes hidden.

How to do this?

Comment: How are you getting the values for the labels? Are they stored in an array?

Comment: You shouldn't be checking the labels. You should be checking the data used by your data source to populate the label.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 scenarios you can deal with.

The first one.
You may want that when your `tableView` appears it just only contains cells with different values inside the labels. In this case, like rmaddy said, you have to properly filter the tableView data source, in order to avoid repeated values, and then show the tableView.

The seconde one.
You want to show the "initial" tableView with repeated values and then update it to show only cells with different values inside the labels (maybe through an animation). In this scenario, you can filter the source data and then call `[tableView reloadData]` or you can detect which are the cells that have to disappear (that is retrieving their `NSIndexPath`) and then update tableView through

```
[tableView beginUpdates]
// Here use deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

[tableView endUpdates]
```